# Is there a way to initialize a single element in an array? (Java)

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class Test{
    int[] array = new int[10];
    array[3] = 1;
}
```

this keeps giving a syntax error(syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token). is it not possible to initialize only a single element from the array?

Comment: where is method declaration ?

Comment: Why so many downvotes? What is wrong with the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have code at the top level within your class, which isn't allowed in Java. You can declare and initialise variables like this:

```
public class Test{
    int[] array = new int[10]; // OK
}
```

But you can't execute other statements

```
public class Test{
    int[] array = new int[10];  // OK
    array[3] = 1;  // Not OK
}
```

You can put initialisation statements in an instance initializer block `{}`:

```
public class Test{
    int[] array = new int[10];  // OK

    {
        array[3] = 1;  // OK
    }
}
```

...or in a constructor method:

```
public class Test{
    int[] array = new int[10];  // OK

    public Test(){
        array[3] = 1;  // OK
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this exactly is it, i think!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a main method?

```
public static void main(String[] args){

}
```

If you don't you need one.

> in the Java language, when you execute a class with the Java interpreter, the runtime system starts by calling the class's main() method. The main() method then calls all the other methods required to run your application.
>   If you try to run a class with the Java interpreter that does not have a main() method, the interpreter prints an error message.

http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr96/cs333/java/tutorial/java/anatomy/main.html

Main method aside, you need to put that code inside a method because
at Class level, only the following are allowed:

1. Constructor definitions
2. Method definitions
3. Inner class definitions (including interfaces and enums)
4. Field definitions
5. Initializer blocks (static or dynamic / instance)

Statements are not allowed, they must be nested inside one of the above.

---

so

```
 public class Test{
    int[] array = new int[10];
    array[3] = 1;
 }
```

won't work, but

```
public class Test{
    int[] array = new int[10];

    { // this is a dynamic initializer,
      // it runs after the constructor's
      // first line
        array[3] = 1;
    }
 }
```

will. However, putting the initialization inside a method is preferred.

Comment: @UnknownOctopus that's what i wrote.

Comment: @DizzyCode I started with a suggestion to put his code inside a main method, which i then built on, i published too early.

Comment: I actually thought that every Java program needs a main() method, so this taught me something new.

Comment: @DizzyCode Well, every Java program needs a main() method **_or_** a static initializer. However, I don't know if OP is missing one or not, because the main could be in another class (probably why i got downvoted)

Comment: thanks! i didn't know i had to put thi initializing line inside {}. and yep i have main() in another class. anyway, it's kinda irrelevant but what does OP stand for??

Comment: @tareviverat OP stands for original poster, a.k.a,  you ;-)